# Can not zoom on both axis when use rangeslider on xaxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, plotly

I can not share my actual code heare because of some privercy but i am sharing one example from codepan.
Whenever im using the range slider property in the xaxis property of layout property in plotly.js, the rangeslider is showing and i can not zoom on xaxis with zoom button so how can i do that
Heare is the both example of the code which i have modifyed in codepan

```
layout:{
 xaxis:{
  title:'Year',
  rangeslider:{}
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I am answering my question because i found the solution.
when developer use the rangeslider the plotly provide a slider on the axis, so developer can zoom on that axis with the slider.
as we can see in this image which i have provided
[example with rangeSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJPNe.png)